# Cannot upload big amount of text to my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a website UI. When I enter text line by line in a textarea, it will upload it to my MYSQL database. It works perfectly fine when its small amount (like 10K lines), but with 20K it doesn't work anymore.

I tried editing `php.ini`, by increasing the `max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit, post_max_size, upload_max_filesize` really high. I made sure that the changes were saved and they were. I tried again and it still didn't work.

Comment: What size/type is the database field? Are you getting a database error? Did you restart Apache (or nginx) to make sure your changes take effect?

Comment: _...doesn't work anymore_ - can you elaborate? Is the web server timing out or is the issue happening when you insert the data? Also, post the relevant code your form handler. If it is the database that's bombing, please tell us the relevant details about it.

Comment: have a look at your data base and check the data type for that particular column  example: if it's set to `varchar(20)` it wont take more than 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Does your database field can contain 20k + lines of text ?

*e.g* what is it : `varchar`, `text`, `blob`, `longtext` ?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: I would. But I can't. I don't have enough reputation on stackoverflow